# Adding response value and Javascript value to a field value

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Ajax call is as follows:

```
success: function(response) {
    //alert("Successful ajax call.");
    moveValuesToScreen(response);
},
```

The `moveValuesToScreen`function is below:

```
function moveValuesToScreen(per) {
  var a = per.aBals.cBal;
  alert(a);
  var b = document.getElementById("tAmt").value;
  alert(b);
  var total = a + b;
  alert(total)
  $("#toNewBal").val(total);
}
```

The alert for 'a' comes as undefined and `$("#toNewBal").val(total) = 0`.

```
$("#toNewBal").val(permit.acctBals.currentBal) + b; -- Doesnt work
$("#toNewBal").val(permit.acctBals.currentBal + b); -- Doesn't work
```

Doesn't work in the sense no compile time error but at run time gives `$0`.
My question is how to add a form value to a response object inside the `moveValuesToScreen()`.

Comment: can show us what is the expected value of response?

Comment: @SpringLearner - $("#toNewBal").val(permit.acctBals.currentBal);gets value of $27,002. I have to add say like $12 to that amount.

Comment: I see nothing in the question that has anything to do with the jQuery Validate plugin.  Edited tags.

Comment: try converting your variables in to integers.  ex: var total = +a + +b; and var a = +per.aBals.cBal;